# programmatically get a fixed product tax in product page

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, tax

I'am looking for a code that permit me to get the fixed product taxe named "ecotaxe" for France.

[image]

Is anyone know how to get this value ?

Thanks,

Comment: Where is this value added? On a product on in the tax module?

Comment: Looks like a custom module that is used for this purpose. You might be able to customise Mage_Weee module to handle the eco tax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "weee tax" in Magento and it's defined by product.

Everything is located in weee_tax table in Magento database. It's something existing by default in Magento but not often used.

I found a solution, hope it'll help :

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-fpt-tax

And my code looks like that after creating the specific attribute :

```
$ecotaxe = $_product->getEcotaxe();
echo $ecotaxe[0]['value'];
```